# Switch back and forth between windows in pyqt5 while avoiding circular imports

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I have 2 windows I want to be able to switch between, **Login** and **MainWindow**, each one is `QWidget` in its own seperate file, **loginUI.py** and **MainUI.py** respectively.

I can easily switch from login to main upon correct authentification by creating a new instance of MainWindow. But in MainWindow I want to have a 'Disconnect' button that shows the Login screen.

Since both are in different files, importing in this scenario raises a circular import error in python.

Other approaches I tried are:

1. Using signals and handling them in an intermediate file. This is fine but as I add more buttons/ windows the file started to become a bit of a mess.
2. Passing the instance of Login to `MainWindow.__init__(self, login)`, and just using `self.login.show()`. Which seems like a good way, but again as I add more and more windows, I'm scared it might affect performance as so many instances are just running in the background.

Is any of these the correcte way or am I missing an easier way

---

**Edit:**

- `login.py`

```py
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize 
    from mainmenu import MainWindow
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    import sys
    
    class Login(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            QWidget.__init__(self)
    
            self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    
            self.setWindowTitle("Log in") 
    
            self.username = QLineEdit(self)
            self.username.move(50, 10)
            self.password = QLineEdit(self)
            self.password.move(50, 40)
            self.connect_button = QPushButton('Connect', self)
            self.connect_button.move(50, 100)
            self.connect_button.clicked.connect(self.handleConnexion)      
    
        def handleConnexion(self):
            if self.username.text() == "admin" and self.password.text()=="1":
                self.mw = MainWindow()
                self.mw.show()
                self.close()
                
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainWin = Login()
        mainWin.show()
        sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

- `mainmenu.py`

```py
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
    
    
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    
            self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    
            self.setWindowTitle("Main menu") 
    
            disconnect_button = QPushButton('Disconnect', self)
            disconnect_button.clicked.connect(self.handeDC)
    
        def handeDC(self):
            pass
            # here I either send a signal to handle it somewhere else
            # or 
            # if i pass the login instance in __init__, just do login.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of your code?  Your best bet is to use signals and slots probably but you shouldn't need to use an intermediate file.

Comment: @alexpdev Since my code current code at the moment is bit messy, I provided a simple prototype of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: since this is a common question, I'll provide a more *broad* answer that better reflects the object hierarchy.</sup>

Since the "main" window is, as the name suggests, the *main* one, the script containing it should be the *main* one, while the login window should be imported and eventually shown as required.

The hierarchy is important: you don't have to consider the order in which the windows are shown, but their relevance.

Considering this, the main script will:

- create the main window;
- show the login if required;
- show the main window if the login is successful;
- show again the login if the user disconnects;
- clear the contents if the user has changed (*see below);

The above also shows why it's rarely a good idea to continuously create new instances of windows.

The login window should also be a QDialog, which makes things easier: the [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) method is "blocking" (for the function execution, not for the event loop), and waits until the dialog is *accepted* or *rejected.

**`main.py`**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from login import Login

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main menu')

        disconnect_button = QPushButton('Disconnect')
        self.setCentralWidget(disconnect_button)

        # only for a *persistent* login dialog (*see below)
        self.login = Login()

        disconnect_button.clicked.connect(self.disconnect)

    def start(self):
        # put here some function that might check for a 'previous' logged in
        # state, possibly stored using QSettings.
        # in this case, we just assume that the user has never previously
        # logged in, so we automatically show the login window; if the above
        # function returns True instead, we can safely show the main window
        logged = False

        if logged:
            self.show()
        else:
            self.showLogin()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.hide()
        self.showLogin()

    def showLogin(self):
        if self.login.exec():
            self.show()

        # alternatively (*see below):
        login = Login()
        if login.exec():
            self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**`login.py`**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Log in')

        self.username = QLineEdit()
        self.password = QLineEdit()
        self.password.setEchoMode(self.password.Password)
        self.connect_button = QPushButton('Connect', enabled=False)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Username:'), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.username, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Password:'), 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.password, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.connect_button, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.connect_button.clicked.connect(self.handleConnexion)
        self.username.textChanged.connect(self.checkFields)
        self.password.textChanged.connect(self.checkFields)

    def checkFields(self):
        if self.username.text() and self.password.text():
            self.connect_button.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.connect_button.setEnabled(False)

    def handleConnexion(self):
        if self.username.text() == 'admin' and self.password.text() == '1':
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 
                'Invalid username or password!')
```

Notes:

- the above code will *always* show the existing `Login` instance, so the username and password fields will "remember" the previous entries; if you don't want that, you can always call [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clear) on those fields by overriding the `exec()` (but remember to call the base implementation and return its result!); alternatively, don't create the `self.login` and always create a new, local instance of `Login()` in `showLogin()`;
- you shall *always* use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and **never rely** on fixed geometries;
- QMainWindow should *always* have a [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), creating children of a main window using it as the parent is discouraged (unless you *really* know what you're doing); if you need more widgets, use a basic QWidget, set a layout for it, add the children, and finally call `setCentralWidget()`;
- more complex hierarchies can require a "controller" (read more about the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) to better organize the whole program and respect the OOP patterns; this is normally achieved by a basic class or by subclassing the QApplication;
- about the last (*) point in my initial list, and related to what explained above: a "controller" could/should completely delete the previous "main window" (it would be both easier and safer) and eventually show a new instance whenever the user has disconnected;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing the `Login` widget when creating the `MainWindow` widget, you could just hide the widget, which will save the overhead of creating a new instance and also keep the connected slots intact.

Then on your `MainWindow` you can create a `diconnected` signal that should be emited when the user clicks the disconnect button.

The login window can listen for the signal and call it's `show` method.

I made inline comments where I made changes in the example below:

mainwindow.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal  # added this

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    disconnected = pyqtSignal()  # added this

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ...
        disconnect_button = QPushButton('Disconnect', self)
        disconnect_button.clicked.connect(self.handeDC)

    def handeDC(self):
        # ... do some stuff
        self.disconnected.emit() # added this
```

login.py

```
class Login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        ...

    def handleConnexion(self):
        if self.username.text() == "admin" and self.password.text()=="1":
            self.mw = MainWindow()
            self.mw.disconnected.connect(self.show)  # added this
            self.mw.show()
            self.hide()   # changed this

...
```